# How to propagate a MouseEvent such as onEntered/onExited?

Tags: qml

According to the [Qt documentation on MouseArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop), only a 'composed' event such as clicked can be propagated to an item that is lower in z-order.

How can I replicate the same behaviour for a simple mouse event such as onEntered or onExited?

e.g. I have two rectangles, both with a MouseArea, where the upper rectangle covers the bottom right corner of the lower rectangle. If I click anywhere on either rectangle, including the overlapped region, both rectangles' MouseAreas will receive the `onClicked` signal because I've used `propagateComposedEvents: true` and set `mouse.accepted = false` in the handler of upperRect. However `onEntered` only works on the non overlapped portion of lowerRect.

```
Rectangle {
    id: lowerRect
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "blue"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("lowerRect was clicked")
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: console.log("lowerRect was entered")
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: upperRect
    x: 50
    y: 50
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "green"
    opacity: 0.8

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: {
            mouse.accepted = false
            console.log("upperRect was clicked")
        }
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: console.log("upperRect was entered")
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that's not exactly what you are looking for, but you can rely on signals for that. A bit tricky anyway, but you can get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually call signals. Something like `myMouseArea.entered()` or `myMouseArea.exited()` (where `myMouseArea` is the `id` or reference to a `MouseArea` object) will work.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm new to Qt and just getting the hang of signals & slots. Are you saying that I'd create slots on the MouseArea of the lowerRect and generate signals from the MouseArea of the upperRect? Or do you have something more elegant in mind that might work where there are, say, 100 rectangles, in play?

Comment: Yes, that is my solution to this problem. If you want to handle 100 `Rectangle`s you can store references to them in JavaScript `Array` and propagate signals with a `for` loop. If you want more information please be specific and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I confused two things in my question. I asked how you could propagate a signal and you've answered that, so I've ticked your answer. However I want to detect when the mouse enters the lower rectangle even when the mouse is already within the upper rectangle (i.e. when the upper rectangle doesn't receive onEntered). I've edited the example in my question so that it doesn't confuse the two questions... and I've asked the other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776373/how-could-i-detect-an-onentered-signal-on-an-object-that-is-beneath-another-obje